# Return blank or zero values from dataframe only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) which looks like:

```
Date        Last Value
29/12/2017      45.675
28/12/2017           0
27/12/2017      45.665
26/12/2017      45.635
25/12/2017  
22/12/2017      45.625
21/12/2017      45.645
20/12/2017      45.655
19/12/2017      45.689
```

How can I return rows that have either a blank or a zero only?  So the desired returned output from the above would be:

```
28/12/2017           0
25/12/2017
```

Where the values are either blank or 0.

Comment: Are these blanks actual whitespaces or `NaN`?

Answer (score 2):

This will return all rows where there is either **a)** an empty space, or **b)** equals zero (as a numeric value, not string)

```py
df.loc[(df['Last Value'].str.contains(r'^\s*$')) | (df['Last Value'] == 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fill NaN with zero and select rows with a zero value

```
df[df['Last Value'].fillna(0) == 0]

         Date  Last Value
1  28/12/2017   0.0
4  25/12/2017   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` to flag any non-numeric to `NaN`. After that check with `isin`

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df.LastValue, errors='coerce').isin([0, np.nan])
df[m]

Out[265]:
         Date LastValue
1  28/12/2017         0
4  25/12/2017
```

---

Above solution is assumed you look for all rows where values is `0` or Non-numeric. If you specifically look for only blank spaces and `0`, Use this following mask

```
m = df.LastValue.astype(str).str.strip().isin(['', '0', '0.0'])

Out[272]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: LastValue, dtype: bool
```

Then, use it to slice as `df[m]` the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the argument `errors = 'coerce'` and 
then discard values ​​greater than 0 :

```
mask=pd.to_numeric(df['LastValue'],errors = 'coerce')>0
new_df=df[~mask]
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
         Date  LastValue
1  28/12/2017        0.0
4  25/12/2017
```

Answer (score -1):

For zero you can try this

```
df[df['Last Value'].eq(0).all(1)]
```

I am not sure about blank but try

```
df[df['Last Value'].eq('').all(1)]
```